# React Application is not loading in developement mode on vite in Google Chrome on Linux Systems (Ubuntu, Manjaro)

Tags: reactjs, linux, google-chrome, vite

while developing a react application on vite, on ubuntu system,
I've encountered an infinite loading of app when try to run it in google chrome.

On the other hand when I start it in firefox it works fine.

May be somebody encountered such a problem and knows a way how to resolve this kind of problem?

This happens only on Linux sys, on Mac or Windows application runs without problems in Chrome Browser.

I tried to increase the limit of watchers of ubuntu system to maximum, but this doesn't help.
I tried to remove all chrome extensions + react dev tools - doesn't help.
I tried to find some information related to this problem in internet, but I can't find any usefull information, that's why i ask you guys. May be somebody knows how to cure this behavior )

Comment: See [this](https://vitejs.dev/guide/troubleshooting.html#requests-are-stalled-forever) portion of troubleshooting with Vite.

Comment: hi, a little late but: what do you mean by development mode? trying to connect locally to test the app? 
like: 
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.0.211:5173/

Answer (score 2):

```
# Check current limit
$ ulimit -Sn
# Change limit (temporary)
$ ulimit -Sn 10000 # You might need to change the hard limit too
# Restart your browser
```

This helps me, it was found in docs as it was said previously in comments